# Database design

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling

I am building a music streaming site, where users will be able to purchase and stream mp3's. I have a subset entity diagram which can be described as follows:

[image: ER DIAGRAM]

I want to normalise the data to 3NF. How many tables would I need? obviously I want to avoid including partial dependancies, which would require more tables than just album, artist, songs - but I'm not sure what else to add? Any thoughts from experience?

Comment: If a song is both released as a single and contained in an album, are they considered different songs?

Comment: in that scenario, ideally i would want both listings to come up - if the song in the album and the song released as single

Comment: can multiple artists produce an album?

Comment: i would like that feature, but i'm not sure how to implement such a feature without breaking the laws for 1NF - that is each cell must be single valued.

Comment: That is handled in the Data Model provided.  Actually, did you choose the correct answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need 4 tables: Artists, Songs, Albums, and AlbumSongs.
The last one is required since the exact same song (=same edit/version...) could be included in several albums, so you have there a m-to-m relationship.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you've done the ER level.  You need to identify Keys and Attributes before you can work out Functional Dependencies.  There is a fair amount of work to do before you get to 3NF. Eg. Song Titles are duplicated.

Also, there are questions:

- is the site selling Albums, Songs, or both ? (I've modelled both)
- if both, how do you track a sale or download ?
- do you care about the same Song title recorded by different Artists ?

Anyway, here is a resolved [**▶Entity Relation Diagram◀**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/dr85%20ERD.pdf), at least for the info provided. It is closer to 5NF than 3NF, but I cannot declare it as such, because it is not complete.

Readers who are unfamiliar with the Standard for Modelling Relational Databases may find [**▶IDEF1X Notational◀**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Notation.pdf) useful.

It uses a simple Supertype-Subtype structure, the Principle of Orthogonal Design. The Item that is sold ie either an Album xor a Song.

Feel free to ask clarifying questions.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the information - your ER diagram is much better. Regarding your q's - the site sells both singles and albums - like itunes - users will be able to purchase singles off of an album or the entire album. To track a sale (no downloads - purely streaming) I was thinking of a collection feature, where users will each have a table containing their purchased songs. Same song titles aren't really an issue are they? providing I provide a direct way of identifying the artist and, if appropriate, the album it is off too.

Comment: @drb5. My pleasure. I have provided all that. `Download` is the sold `Item`, a `Song` or `Album`. `SongTitle` etc is all there. Do you want me to model `User` ? Done. Do you understand the super/subtype ?

Comment: Thanks. No that's ok, you already done enough. - I was just a little confused about how to model albums artists songs and how to also include various artists so that users could see which artist produced what song on a compilation cd..

Comment: @dr85. The model allows that, maybe you need to model the Attribute level for that to be clear; or change the meaning of the Verb Phrases (check again). The essence is one producing Artist per Song; plus one producing Artist per Album. SongTitle::Album is n::n.

Comment: @dr 85.  If there are no further questions, please choose an answer (the tick mark).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with iDevelop but with 1 extra table. Here is how I would model it.

Tables: Artist, Song, Album, AlbumSongMap, SingleInfo

If the song was a released as a single on a different date, you can get that from SingleInfo. The single may have been released with some cover art that is different from the album art. You would store the singles art in SingleInfo. MAYBE a song can be released as a single multiple times, with new cover art or something so it could possibly be a 1-many relation. Otherwise it is 1-1.

If you can join Song with SingleInfo that means it was released as a single.  If you can join Song with Album (using the map) then you will find all the album's it was released under.

A digital enhancement to an old song is a new song. (or at least a different binary). You may want to further normalize Song to allow storage of digital enhancements without duplicating songName, etc.

Comment: Presumably, albumsongmap consists of the primary keys from both song and album tables (i.e. catalogueNumber or id)?

Answer (score 0):

When you switch over from ER modeling to relational modeling (tables), you need one table for each entity.  You also need a table for some relationships.

In the diagram you've given us, both relationships are many to one.  Many to one relationships do not require a table.  You can get away with adding foreign keys to entity tables.  Therefore the answer to your question is 3 tables:  Artists, Albums and Songs.

**However**, I question your ER diagram.  It seems to me that the "contains" relationship is really many to many.  An album clearly contains many songs.  But a given song can appear on more than one album.  So there should be an arrowhead on the line that connects "contains" to "album".

If you accept this revision to your ER model,  then the number of tables increases to 4:  Artists, Albums, Songs, and Contains.

A similar argument might be made for Artist and Song.  If two artists collaborate on a single song,  (e.g. Dolly Parton and Kenny Rogers singing "Islands in the Stream" together,
then you might want to model "produces" as a many to many relationship.  Now you need 5 tables:  Artists, Albums, Songs, Contains and Produces.

Artists, Albums, and Songs are going to require a PK that identifies the corresponding entity.  Entity integrity demands that the correspondence bewteen entity instances and table rows be one-to-one.

The Contains and Produces tables can be built without a separate Id attibute. You will need a pair of FKs in each of these tables, and you can declare a compound PK for each table consisting of the two FKs.

Referential integrity demands that you enforce the validity of FK references, either in your programs or by declaring a references constraint in the DB.  I strongly prefer declaring the constraint in the DB.